# Programmatically set JWPlayer to play file from database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jwplayer

I have a querystring on page load that I use to get the filename and thumbnail image for JWPlayer. It is not getting the filename or thumbname, however. There must be a reason why I can't get it over to my aspx page, from the VB code behind.See code:

```
Code Behind (VB):
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim videoName As String = Request.QueryString("FileName")
    Dim thumb As String = Request.QueryString("Thumb")
End Sub
```

And now I need to get these string variables into the .ASPX page to the JWplayer script, but they do not

```
.ASPX:
<div id='container'></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/player/jwplayer.js</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("container").setup({                
            file: videoName,
            flashplayer: '~/player/player.swf',
            volume: 35,
            width: 480,
            height: 270,
            skin: '~/player/skins/skin.zip',
            image: thumb,                
        })
</script>
```

Comment: The error I get is this: 'videoName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Hm, do you have a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ho I solved it

```
Code Behind (VB):

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   Dim videoName As String = Request.QueryString("FileName")
   Dim thumb As String = Request.QueryString("Thumb")
   Dim dur As String = Request.QueryString("Duration").ToString()


    txt1.Text = "~contents/published/" & videoName.ToString()
    txt2.Text = "~/contents/thumbs/" & thumb.ToString()
    txt3.Text = dur.ToString()

End Sub
```

Now to get the value of the query string to the JWPlayer javascript, I had to add a javascript function inside the JW script and I called it codeAddress(). This kind of documentation is NOT found on the LongTail website or tutorials or anywhere else on the internet that I have found.

```
.ASPX:
<script type="text/javascript">
        function codeAddress() {
            var dootoo = document.getElementById('<%=txt1.ClientID%>').value;
            var doothree = document.getElementById('<%=txt2.ClientID%>').value;
            var doofour = document.getElementById('<%=txt3.ClientID%>').value;
            jwplayer("container").setup({
                duration: doofour,
                file: dootoo,
                flashplayer: '~/player/player.swf',
                skin: "~/player/skins/newtubedark.zip",
                volume: 35,
                width: 685,
                height: 385,
                image: doothree,

            })
        }
        window.onload = codeAddress;
    </script>
<asp:textbox id="txt1" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:textbox>
    <asp:textbox id="txt2" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:textbox>
    <asp:textbox id="txt3" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:textbox>
```